# crunch - @%,^ appearing at most 3 times

Tags: crunch

I'm not sure if this question belongs here or into superuser, so feel free to migrate this question.
I'm currently generating a wordlist with the following line

```
crunch 4 4 4536271890 -d 2%
```

the result I get is like this

```
4454
4455
4453
4456
...
```

is it possible to set a maximum for how often a character is used,
e.g. setting % to max 2 I wouldn't get numbers like `4454`, `4544`, `5455`?
If it's not possible with crunch are there other method to accomplish that?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

It appears the latest release has what you want listed as:

> new -d option to limit duplicate characters see man file for details

You can find the download at http://sourceforge.net/projects/crunch-wordlist/

---added---

The following command (using the latest release v3.6 May 2014) produces the results you request:

> crunch 4 4 4536271890 -d 1@ -d 2%

Comment: `... The  format is  number  then  symbol where  number is the maximum number of consecutive characters ...` < From the man page, but I don't want Strings like 4544..

Comment: see update for the syntax